# Network-polling in Cypress

Tags: testing, request, cypress, polling

I have a webapp that processes some data in the background which can take quite some time (~5 minutes). The status of the task can be checked using a simple GET request.

I would like Cypress to send said get request, then wait in case the response does not contain the proper data and repeat this process until a timeout is reached or a maximum number of retries was performed. In case I get the proper reply, I would like to stop retrying and keep on going with my tests.

Does anybody know how that can be achieved?

Comment: Ok, I was trying to make this work for nearly an hour and it's just in the FAQ:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-Polling

Answer (score 0):

You can either used recurse function or use [`cypress-recuse`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) which allows some nifty configs.

```js
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse'

recurse ({
  () => {
    return cy.request('https://www.your-url.com/')
             .its('response')
  },
  (response) => {
     // whatever checks need to complete before proceeding
  },
  {
    // can alter configurations
    timeout: 30_000,
    delay: 3_000,
    limit: 7
  }
)
```